# Generate HTML mail from Google Script issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a strange issue that makes my mind blown, I have a GAS that using MaillApp service to send HTML emails from spreadsheet values, I have two mails that are constructed exactly the same but the HTML emails are sent differently:

**1- This one works correctly:**

```
if(dataArray[row][mailObj['Creation Checkbox']] == "TRUE" && dataArray[row][mailObj['Creation Mail']] == ""){
        var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('creationMail');
        template.url = ss.getUrl() + "#gid=" + sheet.getSheetId();
        template.mailObj = mailObj;
        template.dataArray = dataArray[row];
        template.inputArray = inputArray[0];
        var msg = template.evaluate().getContent();
        var subject = `[New Task] ${dataArray[row][mailObj['Task Serial']]} @ ${dataArray[row][mailObj['Recorded Date']]} - ${dataArray[row][mailObj['Task Name']]} from ${dataArray[row][mailObj['Owner']]}`;

        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: dataArray[row][mailObj['Responsible Email']],
          cc: dataArray[row][mailObj['Owner Email']] + "," + dataArray[row][mailObj['Accountable Email']],
          subject: subject,
          htmlBody: msg,
        })
}
```

```
 <ul>
      <li> <b> Task Serial: </b> <?= dataArray[mailObj['Task Serial']] ?> </li>
      <? inputArray.forEach(input => { 
        if(dataArray[mailObj[input]] != ""){?>
      <li> <b><?= input ?>:</b> <?= dataArray[mailObj[input]] ?>. </li>
      <? }}); ?>
      <li> <b>Recorded Date: </b> <?= dataArray[mailObj['Recorded Date']] ?> </li>
      <li> <b>Expected Date: </b> <?= dataArray[mailObj['Expected Date']] ?> </li>
    </ul>
```

[image]

---

**2- This one doesn't work:**

```
else if(dataArray[row][mailObj['Submission Checkbox']] == "TRUE" && dataArray[row][mailObj['Submission Mail']] == ""){
        var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('submissionMail');
        template.url = ss.getUrl() + "#gid=" + sheet.getSheetId();
        template.mailObj = mailObj;
        template.dataArray = dataArray[row];
        template.outputArray = outputArray[0];
        var msg = template.evaluate().getContent();
        var subject = `[New Submission] ${dataArray[row][mailObj['Task Serial']]} @ ${dataArray[row][mailObj['Submission Date']]} - ${dataArray[row][mailObj['Task Name']]} from ${dataArray[row][mailObj['Responsible']]}`;

        
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: dataArray[row][mailObj['Owner Email']],
          cc: dataArray[row][mailObj['Accountable Email']],
          subject: subject,
          htmlBody: msg,
        })
}
```

```
<ul>
      <? outputArray.forEach(output => { 
        if(dataArray[mailObj[output]] != ""){?>
      <li> <b><?= output ?>:</b> <?= dataArray[mailObj[output]] ?>. </li>
      <? }}); ?>
      <li> <b>Submission Date: </b> <?= dataArray[mailObj['Submission Date']] ?> </li>
      <li> <b>Expected Date: </b> <?= dataArray[mailObj['Expected Date']] ?> </li>
    </ul>
```

[image]

---

Note that **outputArray** is correct and there are no errors.

Comment: Try to log `dataArray[row][mailObj['Creation Checkbox']] `, `dataArray[row][mailObj['Creation Mail']]` and `dataArray[row][mailObj['Submission Mail']]` before the `if` to verify either your values are as expected. What do you mean by ` the HTML emails are sent differently` and `This one doesn't work`?

Comment: the if condition parameters are not the problem, you can see that the logic is the same check the first li for each mail

Comment: But what do you mean by `the HTML emails are sent differently` and `This one doesn't work`?